# Migrate from Archiva to Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, archiva

Has anyone migrated from Archiva to Artifactory before?  I'm looking for some guidance, and am unable to find any info online.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use repositories import and point it to Archiva's storage.
2. Configure Archiva as a remote repository for Artifactory, and run builds for a while. When you're confident all the artifacts were cached, take Archiva down and mark the remote repository offline.

The benefit of the former is a simple and one-time procedure.
The benefit of the later is no downtime and import of only artifacts that are really in use.

Comment: I'm just curious about the reason? The new 2.0.1 version is really fast and include a nice new ui.

Comment: @olamy you know the link to the comparison matrix :-) In a glace: Binary Repository is so much more than just a basic Maven proxy with pain filesystem storage.

Comment: @JBaruch Do I have to understand using a real database is not pain and very more performant :-)  LOL :P

Comment: @olamy guess what, deduplication is so much more performant, you'll be REALLY surprised. But even without considering the huge savings during the promotion and replication operations, Aritfactory 3 is blazing fast. We didn't do much benchmarking against Archiva lately (for the obvious reasons), but we beat Nexus 3 times in the slowest scenarios.

And regarding the promotion and replication, right, Archiva is a simple Maven proxy, what am I talking about?

Comment: @olamy, no particular reason, other than our mgt would like us to consider moving to it.  One of the things the team would like improved is the ability to import repositories into non-internet-connected instances.  We find it difficult with Archiva, currently.

Comment: @cjtightpant looks like a simple directory copy?

Comment: @olamy what's the trigger? How do you know what to copy? How do you sync deletions?